# Detect headphone buttons on swift?

Tags: swift, headphones

Need to be able to detect button keypress on headphone volume rocker (the +, -, and pause/middle button)

What is the best way to do this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect headset button click on iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428783/detect-headset-button-click-on-iphone-sdk)

Comment: to read the headphone's middle button click event, use MPRemoteCommandCenter.
like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58249502/7353852